# Return value from an anonymous class

Tags: android, asynchronous, return, anonymous

I have a code like this :

```
public Dictionary<Object, Object> call(String method, Iterable args)
{
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(getUrl(method, args), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String response) 
            {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();             
    }       
    });
}
```

I would like to be able to return `(Dictionary<Object, Object>) gson.fromJson(response, Dictionary.class)` to my `call` method, but how-to ? I use http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ to have an easy-to-use async HTTP requests system.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Since the gson object isn't created yet at the time `call()` is finished, there won't be anything to return.

There are workarounds, depending upon your specific needs.  In general, you will want to call `gson.fromJson(response, Dictionary.class)` in the `onSuccess()`, place the result in a known location, and send a message back to your app that the data is ready.

Also, since success is not guaranteed, you will need to handle the case where the http request fails.